# I'm using the Jquery each method, I need to get each element's id in the each... I'm getting back undefined, why?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the Jquery each method, I need to get each element's id in the each... I'm getting back undefined, why?

```
 <div class='W'>
      <div class='cImage pull-left'>
           <img src='http://placehold.it/85x54/FFFFFF' />
      </div>
      <div class='cImage pull-left'>
           <img src='http://placehold.it/85x54/000000' />
      </div>
</div>

 <script>
      var idNum = 1;
      $('.W > .cImage').each(function(){
           $(this).attr('id', idNum);
           idNum++;
      });

      setTimeout(function() {
           $('.W .cImage').each(function(idx,el){
                console.log(el.attr('id'));
           });
      }, 5000);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` to get the element reference:

```
console.log($(this).attr('id'));
```

or without jquery object using javascript object:

```
   console.log(this.id);
```

Comment: `this.id` would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

The element given to your `each` callback is a DOM element, not a jQuery element.

Replace

```
console.log(el.attr('id'));
```

with

```
console.log(el.id);
```

Note that there are many possible improvements for a cleaner code :

```
$('.W > .cImage').attr('id', function(i){
   return i+1
});
$('.W .cImage').each(function(){
   console.log(this.id);
});
```

demonstration

Comment: I tip my hat off to you sir.

Comment: Yes, I just typed something up quick and dirty to get a hold of what was going on in the bigger picture.

Now my question is, how do I modify a attribute on a element? .attr doesn't work as I would expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
        $('.W .cImage').each(function(idx){
            console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    }, 5000);
```